# Json Error "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of "

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api

I get some information facebook api and i will parse with Json.But when run the program i am getting `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of` error. When i debug i see "Bad Request" to response.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Seems like your request is wrong hence you are not getting a valid json response. use fiddler and see if your request gets a response?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to parse nothing.

Comment: hi Duygu. If you solved this problem, please tell me about solution :) 
Teşekkürler.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably getting a blank response. Its not null but the response is empty. So you are getting this error and not a Nullpointer exception.

check for some proxy issues. Is the url exposed on the internet?

Comment: in my caser url work fine in browser but not in android can you tell what s mistake