# JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Json Error “org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466915/json-error-org-json-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0-of)

Whenever I make a call to the facebook api , sometimes I get this kind of response:
`10-02 17:30:37.295: D/FACEBOOK(452): JSONException: End of input at character 0` .
When I execute it again it seems to work. But why is this happening in the first place.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11845105/6452709) (link to answer)

Comment: The difference is that I only occasionally run into this issue. I was wondering what the race condition would be leading to this error