# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character

Tags: android, arrays, json

when I try to get json that doesn't have object, it works fine. but when I try go get json that has an object it's getting error.

Have you got any idea?

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url = "http://example.com/adchara1/";
    JSONArray data = null;

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

        MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> map;
        data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("countries");
        data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
            map.put("photo", (String) c.getString("photo"));
            map.put("ImageThumBitmap",(Bitmap) loadBitmap(c.getString("photo")));

            // Full (for View Popup)
            map.put("frame", (String) c.getString("frame"));

            MyArrList.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

error

```
12-26 11:51:10.352: W/System.err(23284): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-26 11:51:10.368: W/System.err(23284):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
12-26 11:51:10.368: W/System.err(23284):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
12-26 11:51:10.368: W/System.err(23284):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
12-26 11:51:10.368: W/System.err(23284):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at com.example.gridview.MainActivity$DownloadJSONFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at com.example.gridview.MainActivity$DownloadJSONFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-26 11:51:10.376: W/System.err(23284):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-26 11:51:10.399: D/libEGL(23284): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-26 11:51:10.423: D/libEGL(23284): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-26 11:51:10.430: D/libEGL(23284): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-26 11:51:10.516: D/OpenGLRenderer(23284): Enabling debug mode 0
12-26 11:51:10.735: D/AndroidRuntime(23284): Shutting down VM
12-26 11:51:10.735: W/dalvikvm(23284): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4158f300)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at com.example.gridview.MainActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(MainActivity.java:122)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:182)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at com.example.gridview.MainActivity.ShowAllContent(MainActivity.java:91)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at com.example.gridview.MainActivity$DownloadJSONFileAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:209)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at com.example.gridview.MainActivity$DownloadJSONFileAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-26 11:51:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(23284):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 11:51:12.509: I/Process(23284): Sending signal. PID: 23284 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Looks like you have NullPointerException in MainActivity line 122. And it clearly indicates the problem is in getCount()

Comment: @AndroSelva see this and tell me http://pastebin.com/mNVGEnD5

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is proper format? use jsonviewer.stack.hu and see if it validates.

Comment: @AndroidKiller did my format isn't good. see this http://pastie.org/5579002

Comment: @kongkea it is good but little too long. :p

Comment: I was getttin the same error because I was using my emulator...I tried on device and JSON parsed correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

to

```
result=getJSONUrl(url);  //<< get json string from server
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

inside `doInBackground` method of `DownloadJSONFileAsync` because currently you are not making any post for getting Json data from the server and just trying to parse an empty string to json

Comment: it works but not display anything. and it say can't JSONObject can't be convert to JSONArray

Comment: @kongkea : because  you are downloading all images and json and then showing in GridView . solution is change your code using lazy loading to show images from web and just store image Url's in Map and in getView method of Adapter try to download require imagesloadBitmap

Comment: can you give me some simple? or Did you have tutorial about Gridview get image from JSON using AsyncTask and Universal-Image-Loader?

Answer (score 5):

as you can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11845105/1056359), you are probably getting a blank response.
in general, the `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character N of...` means that the JSON couldn't be parsed and something is not being done right.

if the problem is that you're getting a blank response, you should make sure you get a response from the server before trying to parse it (like ρяσѕρєя K's answer).

if the problem is a bad JSON, you should try and validate it. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a very good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing you assign anything to result after this `String result = "";` in here pastebin.com/mNVGEnD5
and if you trying to get json object with this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

it'll surely return end of input at character 0 because the string result is empty
maybe you can try to replace it with some jsonString you can use this as an example :

```
{
    "result": "OK",
    "member_id": "32",
    "first_name": "Android",
    "last_name": "JSON",
    "nickname": "HEY",
    "accesskey": "123556332",
    "facebook_id": "0",
    "facebook_token_expire_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "facebook_token_expire_date2": "0000000000000",
    "facebook_token_refresh_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "facebook_token_key": "null",
    "status_active": 1 
}
```

Comment: i assigned string result=""; and also doing JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result); and still getting errror

Answer (score 1):

Please check PHP File URL in Browser if get the data means you have problem in android side if browser not shows the data it means problem in PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

-please check your all json veriables are properly return only json format or not.

- Don’t use "http://localhost" or "http://127.0.0.1".  Use "http://10.0.2.2" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array=    new JSONArray(resultdata);
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
             {                  
                carid.add(jsonObject.getString("Id"));
                carlogo.add(jsonObject.getString("CarImage"));
                carname.add(jsonObject.getString("CarType"));
                prize.add(jsonObject.getString("Price"));
                availibility.add(jsonObject.getString("CarAvailable"));}
```

Comment: u can use this way or u have to make custonclass and can add those all data from the server

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use 
`optJSONObject` instead of `getJSONObject` 
because it will not through exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the probleme is the URL, if your website forces **HTTPS**, you have to make sure that you are using an    **HTTPS** **URL**     in your    **APP**.

```js
String url = "https://example.com/adchara1/";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
carid = new ArrayList<String>();
        carlogo = new ArrayList<String>();
        carname = new ArrayList<String>();
        prize = new ArrayList<String>();
        availibility = new ArrayList<String>();

        ListView carlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listcardetails);
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, carid, carlogo, carname, prize, availibility);
        carlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?