# Insert Data Into MysqlDatabase through JSON Request

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Hello I am trying to insert Data into `Mysql` Database based on User Rating. But I get 1 Error:

The AsyncTask:

```
private class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfile.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("magazi_id", "" + 3));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ratingNumber", String.valueOf(percent)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment",comTxt));

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://my.chatapp.info/order_api/insertData/insert.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }

            try
            {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                code=(json_data.getInt("code"));
                if(code==1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Inserted Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return String.valueOf(code);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Sorry, Try Again",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return String.valueOf(code);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

The insertion method:

```
private void insertDataToDatabaseFromRating() {
        ratingBar = (RatingBar) newLayout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        ratingComment = (EditText) newLayout.findViewById(R.id.ratingComment);
        percent = ratingBar.getRating();
        comTxt = ratingComment.getText().toString();
        if (comTxt.isEmpty()) {
            comTxt = " ";
        }

        MyInsertDataTask task = new MyInsertDataTask();
        task.execute();
    }
```

The .php file where i insert the data

```
<?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project', 'username', 'password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}


$magaziId = $_REQUEST['magazi_id'];
$rating=$_REQUEST['ratingNumber'];
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
$flag['code']=0;
if($handler->query('INSERT INTO ratings VALUES(, $magaziId, $rating, $comment)'){
$flag['code']=1;
}
print(json_encode($flag));
?>
```

The Error:

```
09-20 04:43:11.470    7318-7350/com.order.app.order E/pass 1﹕ connection success
09-20 04:43:11.470    7318-7350/com.order.app.order E/pass 2﹕ connection success
09-20 04:43:11.470    7318-7350/com.order.app.order E/Fail 3﹕ org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I get pass 1 and pass 2 but it fails with this. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: What String getting `result = sb.toString();` line?

Comment: Simply add `Log.e("pass 2", "connection success "+result);` and check what string getting from server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202048/org-json-json-exception-end-of-input-at-character-0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036847/org-json-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character

Comment: i dont want to get a string from the server i want to send information to the server and i dont know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

The .php file:

```
<?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project', 'username', 'password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}


    $magaziId = $_POST['magazi_id'];
    $rating=$_POST['ratingNumber'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $handler->query("INSERT INTO ratings(id, magazi_id, ratingNumber, comment) VALUES('', '$magaziId','$rating','$comment')");
    die();
?>
```

Your Async Task like this:

```
private class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfile.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_rate_data_submit));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("magazi_id", "" + 3));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ratingNumber", String.valueOf(percent)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comTxt));
            try
            {
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://my.chatapp.info/order_api/insertData/insert.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!