# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 3

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to build an android login/registration application using androidstudio and slimframework, everything works with the login but when i try to register, it shows org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0.

Here is my code for the mainactivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener {

TextView txtRegister;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    txtRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edtRegister);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegistrationActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    JSONObject parentObject = null;
    try {
        parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject response = parentObject.getJSONObject("response");

        String error = response.getString("error");
        if(error.equals("true"))
        {
            String message = response.getString("message");
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(error.equals("false"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connexion réussie", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String apiKey = response.getString("apiKey");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashBoardActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("api_key", apiKey);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String name = etUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    if(name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Veuillez rentrer votre adresse mail et mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        HashMap loginData = new HashMap();
        loginData.put("mobile","android");
        loginData.put("email",name);
        loginData.put("password",password);
        PostResponseAsyncTask loginTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, loginData);
        loginTask.execute("http://10.0.3.2/androidapi/v1/login");
    }

}
}
```

Here is my code for th registrationactivity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.EachExceptionsHandler;
import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import okhttp3.Response;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener {
EditText edtNomComplet, edtPasswordR, edtAdresseMail;
Button btnRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    edtNomComplet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNomComplet);
    edtPasswordR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtRPassword);
    edtAdresseMail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtAdresseMail);

    btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    JSONObject parentObject = null;
    try {
            parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
            Boolean success = parentObject.getBoolean("success");
            JSONObject response = parentObject.getJSONObject("response");
            Log.d("appandroid",success.toString());
            String error = response.getString("error");
            if(error.equals("true"))
            {
                String message = response.getString("message");
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(error.equals("false"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Inscription réussie", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String name = edtNomComplet.getText().toString();
    String email = edtAdresseMail.getText().toString();
    String password = edtPasswordR.getText().toString();
    if(name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Veuillez rentrer les informations complétes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        HashMap registrationData = new HashMap();
        registrationData.put("password", password);
        registrationData.put("email", email);
        registrationData.put("name", name);
        registrationData.put("mobile","android");

        Log.d("Appandroid", registrationData.toString());

        PostResponseAsyncTask postTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, registrationData);
        postTask.execute("http://10.0.3.2/androidapi/v1/register");
    }

}
}
```

I've tested the API with a RESTCLIENT and everything works fine, i get the result in JSON forma. But when i try to register using the application it shows:

```
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at com.example.theapplication.appandroid.RegistrationActivity.processFinish(RegistrationActivity.java:52)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:248)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:31)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-22 13:09:01.204 28738-28738/com.example.theapplication.appandroid W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036847/org-json-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character

Comment: Check following things:
1) Are you using the correct http verb. Confirm if the api is GET and you are doing HTTP GET and not HTTP Post. A wrong http verb may cause error response and json parsinh may fail.
2) Check if the json doesn't contain malformed json or extra quotation

Comment: Can you paste the JSON string "result" which you passed in void processFinish(String result)  ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari here is the JSON String result:
{"response":{"error":false,"message":"Inscription avec succ\u00e9s"}}

Comment: @crashOveride The Api is POST and i'm doing an HTTP Post. I tried to validate my JSON with JSONLint and everything is good. But if i click in the btnRegister when i leave a field blank i get a response, but when i put all the informations correctly and i hit the btnRegister it shows org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 
I'm sure that's not a php error or something related with the api.