# Error occurs in Login and signup using API

Tags: java, android, json

I updated the code again and after calling the API its show the null. I don't understand it why i getting this problem in my code. I parse it properly but still i getting problem in signup and login in API. How its work to show the data in the sql database?

MainActivity.java (This is a Registration form )

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button register, log_in;
    EditText Username, Email, Password, Mobile ;
    String Username_Holder, Email_Holder, PasswordHolder, MobileHolder;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURL = "http://codexpertise.com/codexpertise.com/apitest/signup.php";
    Boolean CheckEditText ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Assign Id'S
        Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        Mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);

        register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        log_in = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Login);

        //Adding Click Listener on button.
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Checking whether EditText is Empty or Not
                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    // If EditText is not empty and CheckEditText = True then this block will execute.

                    UserRegisterFunction(Username_Holder,Email_Holder, PasswordHolder, MobileHolder);

                }
                else {

                    // If EditText is empty then this block will execute .
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });

        log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        Username_Holder = Username.getText().toString();
        Email_Holder = Email.getText().toString();
        PasswordHolder = Password.getText().toString();
        MobileHolder = Mobile.getText().toString();


        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Username_Holder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(Email_Holder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(MobileHolder))
        {

            CheckEditText = false;

        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }

    }

    public void UserRegisterFunction(final String Username, final String Email, final String Password, final String Mobile){

        class UserRegisterFunctionClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("username",params[0]);

                hashMap.put("email",params[1]);

                hashMap.put("password",params[2]);

                hashMap.put("mobileno",params[3]);

                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);

                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        UserRegisterFunctionClass userRegisterFunctionClass = new UserRegisterFunctionClass();

        userRegisterFunctionClass.execute(Username,Email,Password,Mobile);
    }

}
```

UserLoginActivity.java

```
public class UserLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Email, Password;
    Button LogIn ;
    String PasswordHolder, EmailHolder;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURL = "http://codexpertise.com/codexpertise.com/apitest/login.php";
    Boolean CheckEditText ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
    public static final String UserEmail = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);

        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        LogIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Login);

        LogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    UserLoginFunction(EmailHolder, PasswordHolder);

                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        EmailHolder = Email.getText().toString();
        PasswordHolder = Password.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder))
        {
            CheckEditText = false;
        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }
    }

    public void UserLoginFunction(final String email, final String password){

        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(UserLoginActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")){

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("username",params[0]);

                hashMap.put("password",params[1]);

                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);

                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        UserLoginClass userLoginClass = new UserLoginClass();

        userLoginClass.execute(email,password);
    }

}
```

HttpParse.java

```
public class HttpParse {

    String FinalHttpData = "";
    String Result ;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
    OutputStream outputStream ;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    URL url;

    public String postRequest(HashMap<String, String> Data, String HttpUrlHolder) {

        try {
            url = new URL(HttpUrlHolder);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(14000);

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(14000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriter.write(FinalDataParse(Data));

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                        )
                );
                FinalHttpData = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            else {
                FinalHttpData = "Something Went Wrong";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FinalHttpData;
    }

    public String FinalDataParse(HashMap<String,String> hashMap2) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> map_entry : hashMap2.entrySet()){

            stringBuilder.append("&");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder.append("=");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

        }

        Result = stringBuilder.toString();

        return Result ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably getting a blank response. Its not null but the response is empty. So you are getting this error and not a Nullpointer exception

Comment: How to fix it? @sasikumar

Comment: This code needs Debugging Nothing else .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.json.JSONException: End of input at character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036847/org-json-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character)

Comment: @KunalPitale Please check PHP File URL in Browser if get the data means you have problem in android side if browser not shows the data it means problem in PHP file

Comment: Here is my api link please check it @Nilu

Comment: @Nilu when i use PHP file URL in browser its shows like this {"resp_code":204,"resp_msg":"Invalid Request"}

Comment: Post your backend code, it might be a problem with backend service

Comment: @Sam I change the code please check it and its showing null message when i get the registration